# React import problem, 'Module not found: Can't resolve'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a folder system in my React project, which you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

I am trying to make import to `index.js`, located in `src/components/KeyboardCard/index.js`, from file `context.js` that is located in `src/context.js`.

[image]

I am getting this error message:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '.../context.js' in 'C:\React\top-board\src\components\KeyboardCard'.

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's two levels higher:

```
import AppContext from '../../context';
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't have triple dots import there, try:**

```
import AppContext from '../../context.js';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have provided the wrong path.

```
import AppContext from '../../context.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to go 2 levels higher you have to do it like this:**

```
../../context
```

Also, you don't have to define file format ".js" there, that's not required.